# quite simple configuring https - working with openssl

Tags: windows, ssl, amazon-web-services, openssl, command-prompt

THis is a quite basic question, and I am not sure why i haven't been able to solve it.

Essentially in this guide
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

I am trying to  get pass by the following step:
Enter the path to the OpenSSL installation:

```
c:\ set OpenSSL_HOME=path_to_your_OpenSSL_installation
```

In particular, `path_to_your_OpenSSL_installation`
When I downloaded and install openssl the folder it is found
`c>OpenSSL` and all its files is found inside that folder, I am not sure how to configure that path.

Another question I have is whats the point of geotrust, or verisign if you can use openssl as https for free.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: this is about configuration, and you do have an aws web services section, so i feel this is still somehow relevant

Comment: @jww I have flagged it _move to SuperUser_

Answer (score 1):

Type `set prog` in command line window to see how similar paths look like:

```
d:\bat>set prog
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files

d:\bat>
```

So you could type either

- `set "OpenSSL_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\OpenSSL"` if you run 64-bit Windows **and** have downloaded 64-bit `OpenSSL` version, or
- `set "OpenSSL_HOME=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\OpenSSL"` in case of 32-bit version of windows **or** `OpenSSL`

Note an error in your guide [To include OpenSSL in your path](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html); should be as follows:

```
set "Path=%OpenSSL_HOME%\bin;%Path%"
```

However, change your `PATH` system environment variable **no sooner than** the `OpenSSL_HOME` variable exists **and** `%OpenSSL_HOME%\bin` points to an existing directory.

Read about `set` [(changes made to the environment variables are valid only for the current command-line session)](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) versus `setx` [(set environment variables permanently)](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html).

Comment: thanks. I then arrive at the following line genrsa 2048 PROMPT>openssl req -new -key privatekey.pem -out csr.pem
Access is denied. any idea why access could be denied?

Comment: Omit all the `PROMPT>` (IMHO its a system Command Line Interface prompt moniker only used in docs); use bare `openssl genrsa 2048 > privatekey.pem` and then `openssl req -new -key privatekey.pem -out csr.pem`

Comment: thanks but then iget openssl genrsa 2048 > privatekey.pem 'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @user3907211 - Ensure OpenSSL is on PATH. See, for example, [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9546324/).

Comment: thanks for your response. OpenSSL is now on path, but when i type openssl genrsa 2048 > privatekey.pem, it returns me the following message "Access is denied"